# How do I add a condition to my find function?

Tags: excel, vba, find

so i have this code, what it does is it finds the word "Hello" on a column and if that String is found on the "J" column the entire row would get deleted, but i wanted to retain all the rows with the word "World" in it even though the cell has both "Hello" and "World" in it. For example:

**Column J**
1 Hello world
2 Hello person
3 Hello everyone
4 Hello person
5 Hello world
6 Hello everyone
7 Hello person
8 Hello world

The only rows that should remain are 1,5, and 8. Thank you, any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Test()
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("J1", ActiveSheet.Range("J65536").End(xlUp))
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("Hello", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically recommend using a `For` loop, starting at the end and working upwards, when you're deleting rows.

This should work for you:

```
Sub test2()
Dim c As Range, SrchRng As Range
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set SrchRng = ws.Range("J1", ws.Range("J65536").End(xlUp))

Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
lastRow = SrchRng.Rows(SrchRng.Rows.Count).Row

With ws
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 10), "Hello") >= 1 And InStr(1, .Cells(i, 10), "world") = 0 Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```